# .NET Geometry Library

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, open-source, geometry

Does anyone know of a good (efficient, nice API, etc.) geometry open source library for .NET?  Some of the operations needed:

- **Data Structures**

  - Vectors (2D and 3D with `float`s and `double`s)
  - Lines (2D and 3D)
  - Rectangles / Squares / Cubes / Boxes
  - Spheres / Circles
  - N-Sided Polygon
  - Matrices (`float`s and `double`s)
- **Algorithms**

  - Intersection calculations
  - Area / Volume calculations

Answer (score 6):

For the Linear Algebra part [Math.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) - especially [Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) - could be an option.

Comment: +1: Math .NET looks like a nice library.

Comment: +1: Looks nice but it's missing most of the things I need

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend RhinoCommon, the open source library of the Rhinoceros 3d modeler from mcneel http://www.rhino3d.com .

It allows for the definition of basically any advanced geometry. geometries (meshes, nurbs, polygons, solids, curve, line, polyline etc) and also intersections that result from this geometry. It's pretty well documented, and also available separate from the rhinoceros modeler.

Documentation: http://4.rhino3d.com/5/rhinocommon/

Github: https://github.com/mcneel/rhinocommon

Standalone build instructions: https://github.com/mcneel/rhinocommon/wiki/Rhino3dmIO-Toolkit-%28OpenNURBS-build%29

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it has a .NET port, but [Open Geometry](http://www1.uni-ak.ac.at/geom/opengeometry.php) might be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

[Geotools.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geotoolsnet/) -- in fact written in java but project can produce .net dll that can be used in managed project.